# can't traverse any node in binary tree

Tags: python

when I run this program, it print `NameError global name 'viewAll' is not defined`

I' m a C programmer, I didn't know why.

`viewAll(this)` is defined in `class binTree`,

Platform:Python 2.7 in windows 7 64 bit

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*-coding:gbk-*-

class binTree():
    def __init__(this, left = None, right = None, data = 0):
        if data == 0:
            this = None
        else:
            this.leftNode = left
            this.rightNode = right
            this.data = data
    def viewAll(this):
        if this != None:
            print this.data,
            viewAll(this.leftNode)
            viewAll(this.rightNode)

def creatBT():
    temp = input('Please input a number, input "0" for end!')
    if temp == 0:
        return None
    else:
        tree = binTree()
        tree.data = temp
        tree.leftNode = creatBT()
        tree.rightNode = creatBT()
        return tree

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = creatBT()
    root.viewAll()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a Python tutorial -- you're not understanding how the instance object works in Python instance methods.

Your problem is here:

```
def viewAll(this):
    if this != None:
        print this.data,
        viewAll(this.leftNode)
        viewAll(this.rightNode)
```

You need to access `viewAll` on the instance you want to call it on:

```
def viewAll(this):
    if this != None:
        print this.data,
        this.leftNode.viewAll()
        this.rightNode.viewAll()
```

I'm not sure what you're intending to do here:

```
    if data == 0:
        this = None
```

but all you are actually doing is pointing the name `this` at `None` in the scope of that one function call. It doesn't change anything about the class instance or anything outside the function.

So, in `viewAll`,

```
    if this != None:
```

will always be `True`, because `this` is again the instance you've called `viewAll` on -- it hasn't been and can't be set to `None`.

---

```
class binTree():
    # I removed __init__ to show you weren't using it
    def viewAll(self):
        print self.data,
        # don't try to show a node that is empty
        if self.leftNode:
            self.leftNode.viewAll()
        if self.rightNode:
            self.rightNode.viewAll()

def creatBT():
    try:
        # don't use input
        temp = int(raw_input('Please input a number, input "0" for end!'))
    except ValueError:
        # in case they don't put in a number
        temp = 0
    if temp == 0:
        return None
    else:
        tree = binTree()
        tree.data = temp
        tree.leftNode = creatBT()
        tree.rightNode = creatBT()
        return tree

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = creatBT()
    # don't try to show the nodes if none were created
    if root:
        root.viewAll()
```

Comment: Also, using `self` instead of `this` as the first parameter is a very strong convention in Python.

Comment: @NiklasB. Since that's not technically incorrect I decided not to pile it on.

Comment: Yes, and you were right to do so, just thought it shouldn't go completely unmentioned, hence the comment (:

Comment: I followed your advice, but it still dosen't work.`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'viewAll'`

Answer (score 0):

Please conform to the standard and use *self* instead of *this*.

```
def viewAll(self):
    print self.data,
    self.viewAll(self.leftNode)
    self.viewAll(self.rightNode)
```

There is no need to test if *self* (or *this*) is None.

*edit* This solution is not correct. Please see agf's answer.

Comment: Your code is wrong. `viewAll` only takes the implicitly passed instance. See my code for how you need to call it.

Comment: You're right. There were so many errors that I didn't catch this one.